# A simple factory_girl question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have two factories (`post_factory.rb`, `comment_factory.rb`) in separate files. I'd like to create a bit complex factory, which will create a post with associated comments for me. I created a third file, called `complex_factory.rb`, and wrote the following code:

```
Factory.define :post_with_comments, :parent => :post do |post|
  post.after_create { |p| Factory(:comment, :post => p) }
end
```

But `rake spec` raises an error, stating that the file is unaware of post and comment factories. At the very next moment, I naïvely  wrote requires at the top:

```
require "post_factory.rb"
require "comment_factory.rb"
```

But that didn't gave any proper result. Maybe this requires actually looking the wrong direction? Or they pretty much don't matter (as registering factories for visibility might be more complex that I assume).

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: Not a real solution, but how about just putting all these things into one file?

Comment: As Milan suggests, put it in one file.

Comment: `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/post_factory.rb"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually i've figured out that files with factories see each other. If we have a `comment_factory.rb` alongside with `post_factory.rb`, this following code will work fine (post factory):

```
Factory.define :post_with_comments do |post|
  post.caption = "Caption"
  post.body "Some dummy text"
  post.after_create { |p| Factory(:comment, :post => p) }
end
```

While `comment_factory.rb` looks as following:

```
Factory.define :comment do |comment|
  comment.body "Some wise comment text"
  comment.post_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The require you added doesn't work because it doesn't have the proper path prefix.

However, factory_girl should be doing this for you automatically.  See [the README in the git repository](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).  It says:

> Factories can either be defined anywhere, but will automatically be loaded if they are defined in files at the following locations:
>
> ```
> test/factories.rb
> spec/factories.rb
> test/factories/*.rb
> spec/factories/*.rb
> ```

You must have your factories outside the default location.  If you can't just move them to the default, then use something like this:

```
Dir[File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "/factories/*.rb"].each do |file|
    require file
end
```